# Liferay Dynamic query projection with two fields

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

I need to use a Dynamic Query with Projection with several fields. Something like that

```
DynamicQuery query = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Purchase.class);      query.add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("primaryKey.purchaseId,primaryKey.otherId").in(DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(ResponseField.class)          
                .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("something").eq("something"))
                .setProjection(ProjectionFactoryUtil.property("primaryKey.purchaseId,primaryKey.otherId"))));
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
ProjectionList projectionList = ProjectionFactoryUtil.projectionList();

projectionList.add(projection1);
projectionList.add(projection2);

dynamicQuery.setProjection(projectionList);
```